# Centos 6 Wrong timezone displaying on Web Page when pulling from server time

Tags: timezone, html, centos6

I'm currently having an issue with the wrong timezone displaying on a web page. I support a Linux environment for a small app development team. Currently we are testing a particular app. For test purposes we have a simple web page showing that the app is live and working. The page itself displays the project title and server time.

This issue is that the web page displays the incorrect timezone, however the time itself is correct.The text displayed is "The time on the server is April 5, 2018 7:18:04 AM CDT." For context I've included a screen shoot.

[time zone issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KujEt.png)

Nothing special going on here. As I said the time is technically correct, but it's displaying Central time when I need it to show Eastern, because the people using the app will be located in the Eastern timezone.

I support the environment itself and am not a developer. However, after speaking with them they ensure me that whatever method is being called is pulling from the server time. I've tested this successfully and am able to manually change the time on the server that it is hosted on, and the web page will reflect that.

Within the environment we are using CentOS 6. Based on my research the timezone information is handled by the file "localtime" within the "etc" directory. I've used several methods to alter this file.

I've tried the following command:

```
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Eastern /etc/localtime
```

I've also tried variations of the command. The server shows the correct time and timezone, but the timezone displayed on the web page never changes.

We have two servers to host apps. The interesting this is that apps that are hosted on the other server are being displayed correctly with the Eastern timezone. I've also tried simply taking the "localtime" file on the correct server, and copying it to the other server within the /etc/ directory. With each attempt doing a server restart.

I realize this is a simple issue, but after trying multiple methods with no success I thought I would seek assistance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the help center, as well as the other articles about asking questions you'll find there.  In this particular example, there's nothing we can do to help you because you did not provide any code.  Everything about the problem you asked has to do with the code of the "simple web page" you described.  You've not even provided a hint here about what language the application is written in, so there's nowhere to start to help you out.

Comment: Thank you, You've been extremely helpful.